# Samba/winbind to AD - the userid mapping

Tags: active-directory, samba, mapping, winbind, nss

Guys I got issue with UID mapping from my AD.

I got Centos 5.5 x64 box and AD witk 2k8 Windows Server.

The problem is with username mapping.
Example:

`getent passwd`
`XF-DEV+prouser01:*:16777231:16777230:Prouserf Prousern:/home/prouser01:/bin/bash`

My smb.conf is

```
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    log level = 1
    workgroup = XF-DEV
    password server = xf-dev
    realm = XF-DEV
    security = DOMAIN
    wins server  = 10.105.59.98
    idmap uid = 16777216-33554431
    idmap gid = 16777216-33554431
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind separator = +
    template shell = /bin/bash
    winbind use default domain = no
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    template homedir = /home/%U
    domain master = no
    local master = yes
    preferred master = no
    dns proxy = no
```

Is it possible that I will be albe to do `su - prouser01` instead of `su - XF-DEV+prouser01` ?

Output from `wbinfo -u` and `wbinfo -g` is the same (by that I mean with domain in the front`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was with changing
`winbind use default domain = no` to `winbind use default domain = yes`

`prouser01:*:16777231:16777230:Prouserf Prousern:/home/prouser01:/bin/bash`